# Return value if not null

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I am trying to write as few lines as possible.
What would be the best way to re-write this in Java? (say we have a "public enum A")

I want to have a way of writing "if something is not null, return it, otherwise, keep going".
I looked into Optional, but Optional.of(...).ifPresent( v -> return v;) does not work, although I wish it did.

Also, if you are asking why I am changing the array inside a for-loop, you can consider that there are multiple initial arrays and I need to test them each.

```
public A getAValue() {
   int[] arr = new int[7];
   A returnValue = null;

   for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {

      //change arr
      returnValue = checkSomeCondition(arr);
      if (returnValue != null) {
         return returnValue;
      }

      //change arr again
      returnValue = checkSomeCondition(arr);
      if (returnValue != null) {
         return returnValue;
      }

      //change arr yet again
      returnValue = checkSomeCondition(arr);
      if (returnValue != null) {
         return returnValue;
      }
   }


   return A.UNKNOWN;
}

public A checkSomeCondition(int[] arr) {
   if (arr[0]==arr[1]) {
      return arr[0]==2 ? A.VALUE_1 : A.VALUE_2;
   }

   return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll look into the solutions. Meanwhile, here's the code:https://github.com/imosescu/XsiO. It's a tic-tac-toe :)

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what kind of test your doing or how you are altering
your arrays but this may be possible:

This should ignore all `null` return values and only return the
 `first successful` test result.

If no successes, a `default` return object must be supplied.

```
enum A {
    A_VALUE_1, A_VALUE_2, A_UNKNOWN
};

List<Object[]> testArrays = new ArrayList<>();
testArrays.add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
testArrays.add(new int[] { 3, 4, 5 });
testArrays.add(new int[] { 2, 2, 6 });

A res =
        // stream the set of arrays   
        testArrays.stream()

        // apply each set in order to the method
        // replacing the array under test with the
        // method result
        .map(arr->checkSomeCondition(arr))

         // filter out any null results
         .filter(result->result!=null)

         // get the first non-null result
         .findFirst()

         // return the result or some default answer if all
         // results were null.
         .orElseGet(()->A.A_UNKNOWN);

System.out.println(res);
```

With the supplied data, prints

```
A_VALUE_1
```

Your test method

```
public A checkSomeCondition(int[] arr) {
    if (arr[0] == arr[1]) {
        return arr[0] == 2 ? A.A_VALUE_1 : A.A_VALUE_2;
    }

    return null;
}
```

The down side is it requires you to supply an array of arrays where subsequent ones are to be used if the previous test fails. You may be able to adapt the concept to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q:** I looked into Optional, but Optional.of(...).ifPresent( v -> return v;) does not work, although I wish it did

[`Optional::ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) works, but different than intended. The `return` is within the method implementation of the `Consumer`. Moreover, the `Consumer` doesn't return anything, the method return type is [void](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept-T-).

> **Q:** I am trying to write as few lines as possible.

You achieve what you want with the help of a predefined set of the array suppliers `Supplier<int[]>` and another for-loop inside the already existing one with a number of iterations the same as a number of conditions.

```
List<Supplier<int[]>> arrays = new ArrayList<>();
arrays.add(() -> firstArraySource());
arrays.add(() -> secondArraySource());
...

for (...) {                                         // your initial loop
    for (Supplier<int[]> arraySupplier: arrays) {   // iterate through Suppliers
        arr = arraySupplier.get();                  // get an array (here is the evaluation)
        returnValue = checkSomeCondition(arr);      // getting the 'A' value
        if (returnValue != null) {                  // returnin if not null
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that if the sources of arrays are ex. from the database, they won't be called *before* they are actually needed since they are wrapped in the Suppliers. The calculaiton happens when `Supplier::get` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Optional.ofNullable` instead of `Optional.of` as the latter can't be used for possibly null values. That would work, as well as delegating that task to `checkSomeCondition` function:

```
public Optional<A> checkSomeCondition(int[] arr) {
    if (arr[0] == arr[1]) {
        return Optional.<A>of(arr[0]==2 ? A.VALUE_1 : A.VALUE_2);
    }
    return Optional.<A>empty();
}
```

...and then checking the presence of value in `getAValue`.

The condition can then be checked in a loop, i.e.

```
public A getAValue() {
    int[] arr = new int[7];
    final int maxChecks = 10;
    Optional<A> returnValue = Optional.<A>empty();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int j = 0;
        while (!returnValue.isPresent() && j < maxChecks) {
             returnValue = checkSomeCondition(arr);
             j++;
        }
        return returnValue.get();
    }
    return A.UNKNOWN;
}
```

Comment: Using Optional is fine but the OP still has to have the same structure so it doesn't reduce the code.